# В Listview не работают колонки

Tags: wpf, listview, uwp

В Listview настроил хедеры. Все отлично работает. Думал аналогично добавить и сами строки - но тут как то коряво все отображается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid  Background="Gray">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <TextBlock Text="Блюдо" Grid.Column="0"         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Цена" Grid.Column="1"          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="Количество"  Grid.Column="2"   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding bludo}" Grid.Column="0"    FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding tsena}" Grid.Column="1"    FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding kol}"   Grid.Column="2"    FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

Comment: Что-то вы сами таблицу изобретаете. Почему не встроенный GridView? А вообще как ни крути для таблиц лучше DataGrid

Comment: @vitidev: На мой вкус, `DataGrid` ужасен в смысле отображения, и подходит только для прямого представления таблиц (что почти никогда не нужно нормальному пользователю).

Comment: @Radzhab: Ну так возьмите Snoop и посмотрите, что конкретно вам портит layout.

Comment: что за Snoop????

Comment: @VladD конечно ужасен. но он хотя бы настраивается - убрать разделители и визуализацию начал строк и вот в итоге будет то, что и на скрине

Comment: @vitidev: И заголовки цвета buttonface, их тоже надо убрать. И тогда он будет похож на дефолтный `ListView`. А если у вас Item — не контейнер примитивных типов, а реальный объект, всё становится намного сложнее.

Comment: @VladD О какой такой сложности вы говорите? Я в упор не вижу разницы между самопалом из тс, ListView+GridVIew и DataGrid в плане биндинга - биндится коллекция объектов

Comment: Ну, если свойство объекта — не примитивный тип, как `DataGrid` его покажет?

Comment: @VladD Разве это проблема DataGrid? Любой контрол не может знать как отображать сложные объекты и в таких условиях выдаст ToString() и для решения этого нужно делать {Binding Property.SubProperty}

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, лучше не `Binding` к `Property.Subproperty`, а `<local:PropertyPresenterUserControl DataContext="{Binding Property}"/>`, потому что не дело шаблона в DG знать, как показывать данный тип. Это означает, что для любого нетривиального UI DG не подходит.

Comment: @VladD Кому как не шаблону знать. Ведь он знает на какой объект он биндится.  Для этого даже DataType указывается. Но если хочется чтобы он поменьше знал, то для этого есть а) конвертеры б) кастомные поля во вьюмодели, что сами залезут куда надо в обернутой модели в) DataTemplate-сы c DataType Плодить юзерконтрол нужно только в 2 случаях: а) он переиспользуется б) туда вынесен кусок xaml для улучшения читабельности и разделения. По проблеме тс - я не заметил метку uwp и не знаю что в ней, но в wpf проще взять датагрид (ну если знать как раскрасить хидеры)

Comment: @vitidev: Ну, `DataTemplate`, то же, что и `UserControl`. Но подождите, а если нам нужен не стандартный энтерпрайзный табличный лейаут (допустим, мы пишем не программу для складского учёта или тому подобное скучное _изделие_), а что-то для людей. И у нас нужно составить фразу, в которой некоторые поля берутся из разных частей VM, и показать её. И ещё сверху картиночку. Как с таким справится DG?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42802/discussion-between-vitidev-and-vladd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно выравниваете ваши колонки, нужно ведь общую группу в `Grid` задать (`SharedSizeGroup`). Но проще и правда воспользоваться `View=GridView`, если вам нужен скучный табличный лэйаут:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Название" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Цена" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Количество" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

У меня получилось:

[image: скриншот]

---

**Обновление.**

Окей, в UWP всё сложнее. У меня получилось растянуть колонки так:

```
<ListView ...>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <!-- всё остальное -->
```

Comment: к сожалению у меня UWP и ваш код не работает

Comment: @Radzhab: Окей, попробуйте дополнение в ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте ItemsContainerStyle к ListView с таким содержимым:

```
<Style 
        x:Key="MyListViewItemsContainerStyle"
        TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
</Style>
```